# Removing values from a returned linq query

Tags: linq

HI there I am hoping for some help with a query I have.

I have this query

```
var group =
    from r in CustomerItem
    group r by r.StoreItemID into g
    select new { StoreItemID = g.Key, 
                 ItemCount = g.Count(), 
                 ItemAmount = Customer.Sum(cr => cr.ItemAmount), 
                 RedeemedAmount = Customer.Sum(x => x.RedeemedAmount) 
               };
```

I am returning my results to a list so I can bind it listbox.

I have a property called EntryType which is an int. There are 2 available numbers 1 or 2

Lets say I had 3 items that my query is working with

2 of them had the EntryType = 1 and the 3rd had EntryType2. The first records had a ItemAmount of 55.00 and the 3rd had a ItemAmount of 50.00

How can I group using something simlar to above but minus the ItemAmount of 50.00 from the grouped amount to return 60.00?

Any help would be great!!

Comment: What is 'Customer' in your query?

Comment: It seems you don't really want to remove any values, you want to add some and subtract others. Your title is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what the question is - are you just trying to ignore all items with an entry type of 2? To put it another way, you only want to *keep* entries with an entry type of 1? If so, just add a `where` clause:

```
var group = from r in CustomerItem
            where r.EntryType == 1
            group r by r.StoreItemID into g
            select new { 
               StoreItemID = g.Key, ItemCount = g.Count(), 
               ItemAmount = Customer.Sum(cr => cr.ItemAmount),
               RedeemedAmount = Customer.Sum(x => x.RedeemedAmount)
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `ItemAmount = ...` to:

```
ItemAmount =
   g.Where(x => x.EntryType == 1).Sum(cr => cr.ItemAmount) -
   g.Where(x => x.EntryType == 2).Sum(cr => cr.ItemAmount),
```

I changed `Customer` to `g` because this seems to be an error, but it's not clear to me from your question what you mean here, so maybe this change is not what you want.

A slightly more concise method is to use test the entry type in the sum and use the ternary operator to choose whether to add the positive or negative value:

```
ItemAmount = g.Sum(cr => cr.EntryType == 1 ? cr.ItemAmount : -cr.ItemAmount),
```

This gives the value of 60.00 as you required.